# Filter by field on relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a very special case in which I want a group entity that have a list with the elements that fit some conditions.

These are the ORM class that I have defined:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, Identity(1, 1), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    elements = relationship('Element', foreign_keys='[Element.group_id]')

class Element(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'elemnts'
    id = Column(Integer, Identity(1, 1), primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    value = Column(Numeric(38, 10), nullable=False)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), nullable=False)
```

Now, I want to retrieve a group with all the elements of a specific date.

```
result = session.query(Group).filter(Group.name == 'group 1' and Element.date == '2021-05-27').all()
```

Sadly enough, the Group.name filter is working, but the retrieved group contains all elements, ignoring the Element.date condition.

As suggested by @van, I have tried:

```
query(Group).join(Element).filter(Group.name == 'group 1' and Element.date == '2021-05-27')
```

But I get every element again. On the logs I have noticed:

```
SELECT groups.id AS group_id, groups.name AS groups_name,  element_1.id AS element_1_id, element_1.date AS element_1_date, element_1.value AS element_1_value, element_1.group_id AS element_1_group_id 
FROM groups JOIN elements ON groups.id = elements.group_id LEFT OUTER JOIN elements AS elements_1 ON groups.id = elements_1.group_id 
WHERE groups.name = %(name_1)s
```

There, I noticed two things. First, the join is being done twice (I guess one was already done just getting groups, before join). Second and most important: the date filter doesn't appear on the query.

The driver I'm using the mssql+pymssql driver.

Comment: Are you not getting a warning like this "SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM" when executing?

I think your query needs a join: `query(Group).join(Element).filter(Group.name == 'group 1' and Element.date == '2021-05-27')`.

Comment: Yes I get that warning, but if I use your query (already tried) I get the same result. Anyway, In noticed something on the logs, please see my edited answer.

Comment: it looks like you have a `relationship` setup between `Group` and `Element`, but you do not show it in your code.

Comment: I do show it, on Group class. `date_values = relationship('FixingTickerValueRecord', foreign_keys='[DateValues.group_id]')`

Comment: So `FixingTickerValueRecord` is actually `Element`? what about `DateValues`? I am really confused now.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, I changed the names to be more meaningful to people reading here. I knew I would miss one or two :-(

Comment: ok, thank you. And also it seems that you relationship might be having `lazy="joined"` or `lazy=False`, but your sample code does not show that. Is it true?

Comment: Yeah, true, I had lazy="joined", but I didn't notice any change adding or removing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, there seem to be a combination of few things happening here.

---

First, your relationship `Group.elements` will basically always contain all Elements of the Group. And this is completely separate from the filter, and this is how SA is supposed to work.

You can understand your current query (`session.query(Group).filter(Group.name == 'group 1' and Element.date == '2021-05-27').all()`) as the following:

> "Return all `Group` instances which **contain** an `Element` for a given date."

But when you iterate over the `Group.elements`, the SA will make sure to return **all** *children*. This is what you are trying to solve.

---

Second, as pointed out by [Yeong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67759346/99594), you cannot use simple python `and` to create an `AND` SQL clause. Please fix either by using `and_` or by just having separate clauses:

```
result = (
    session.query(Group)
    .filter(Group.name == "group 1")
    .filter(Element.date == dat1)
    .all()
)
```

---

Third, as you later pointed out, your relationship is `lazy="joined"` and this is why whenever you query for `Group`, the related `Element` instances will ALL be retrieved using `OUTER JOIN` condition. This is why when adding `.join(Element)` to your query resulted in two JOINs.

---

**Solution**

You can "trick" SA to think that the it loaded all `Group.elements` relationship when it only loaded the children you want by using [`orm.contains_eager()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager) option, in which your query would like like this:

```
result = (
    session.query(Group)
    .join(Element)
    .filter(Group.name == "group 1")
    .filter(Element.date == dat1)
    .options(contains_eager(Group.elements))
    .all()
)
```

*Above should work also with the `lazy="joined"` as the extra JOIN should not be generated anymore.*

**Update**

If you would like to get the groups even if there are no Elements with the needed criteria, you need do:

- replace `join` with `outerjoin`
- place the filter on `Element` inside the `outerjoin` clause

```
result = (
    session.query(Group)
    .filter(Group.name == "group 1")
    .outerjoin(
        Element, and_(Element.group_id == Group.id, Element.date == dat1)
    )
    .options(contains_eager(Group.elements))
    .all()
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's clear I need to improve a lot my understanding of SQLAlchemy ORM, and this answer will help me a lot with that. Thank you for providing not only the working code, but the explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I have one more thing pending. The above code will return no rows if there aren't any matching elements. When there are no elements matching the date, I still want to get the group information.

Comment: updated the answer coving this case as well.

Comment: Thank you!! I spent a lot of time getting alchemy not to double join. contains_eager helps me

Answer (score 3):

The `and` in python is not the same as the `and` condition in SQL. SQLAlchemy has a custom way to handle the conjunction using `and_()` method instead, i.e.

```
result = session.query(Group).join(Element).filter(and_(Group.name == 'group 1', Element.date == '2021-05-27')).all()
```

Comment: That's something I didn't know, but actually there's something more that is not working. Even if I use only Element.date condition, `.filter(Element.date == '2021-05-27')` the groups come with all its elments, unfiltered.

Comment: Sorry that I have missed out the `join` part and already mentioned by the comment in the question. You simply need to join the `Group` and `Element` class and the rest will be handled by SQLAlchemy based on the foreign key column. I have edited the answer accordingly.